# How do I make an ISO from a working SD card?

Tags: linux, iso, sd-card

I have this frankenstein Linux, that works on a specific device that multiple people use in a forum.
I have found a way to improve upon the work of someone on the forum, who shared his ISO, and want to share my image to that creator of this original ISO file.

The ISO doesn't need to include installation files.
It's just a working Linux partition with a boot partition.
Can I just do:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/pi/Downloads/WorkingLinux.iso bs=1M
```

Or do I need to approach it from another angle?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes,** the command you're thinking of will certainly produce a disk image file that can be written to another similar disk. But calling it an `ISO` file will only make sense if the disk actually contains an ISO9660 filesystem intended to be burned on a CD-ROM or DVD. The ISO9660 standard and its extensions define a procedure for booting from a CD-ROM that is significantly different from how booting is handled on hard-disk-like media. The newer UDF filesystem specification is much the same, but for larger-capacity and/or rewritable optical media.

Many modern Linux ISO images now have the feature that they can also be written to a hard-disk-like media (e.g. USB stick, SD card or similar) and they will be bootable - but that has actually nothing at all to do with the ISO9660 filesystem format. These images have gone through an additional `isohybrid` process that adds an extra hard-disk-like partition table to the ISO image, allowing the same image file to support two different kinds of boot processes: one for hard-disk-like media, and another for optical media.

Calling something an `ISO` image file carries with it an implicit promise that you can burn it to a CD-ROM, DVD or Blu-Ray and it will produce a working optical disk. If that is not actually the case (i.e. the filesystem type used is neither ISO9660 nor UDF, or it contains a partition table and multiple partitions), then you should not use the `.iso` suffix, but instead `.img` or `.ima`. These suffixes are recognized as more general "disk or filesystem image files", and don't include any implicit claim about being related to optical discs at all.

Yes, this is just a minor nitpick, but it's a pet peeve of mine.

Answer (score 1):

I can also say "Yes, the command you're thinking of will certainly produce a disk image file that can be written to another similar disk".

But it is not the most efficient way to do it. An alternative is to use [**Clonezilla**](https://clonezilla.org), which is a tool to clone or create a [compressed] image of the content of a drive.

- Download a Clonezilla iso file,
- create a USB boot drive,
- boot from it and
- let Clonezilla do it for you.

Clonezilla is smart enough to only copy used blocks in the file system(s) and skip free space. It will also compress the image, so it is both faster and creates a much smaller image (compared to plain cloning like you suggest in the question). The image is not one file, but a directory with a set of files, and you use Clonezilla to restore from the image.

Clonezilla has also several checkpoints to help you identify the drives and make sure that, when backing up, you are reading from the correct drive, and when restoring, that you are writing to the correct drive.